# Will this invalidate my meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

I am pooling scores for my meta-analysis. The outcome measure is the proportion of children that pass a task.

The data reported is given in three ways:

1) When children are tested with the task multiple times: mean % of children correct, total number of children tested, and standard deviation of mean % reported.

2) When children are tested only once: easy enough to report the number of children who succeed and fail at the task.

3) Same as (1), except quite often researchers will NOT report the standard deviation of the mean % children correct (which is what i'm stuck with).

In the case of (3), i have simply treated the data as if the children were only given the task once, and used the mean % correct and total number of children tested to calculate the number of children who succeeded and failed at the task.

I know i could do the same and convert the values in the case of (1) and treat the data as if the children only did the task once, would this be fine? It seems as if i am not utilising all the infomation i have because clearly when the task is given multiple times (as is the case for 1 & 3) the mean % will have a smaller standard error compared to when it is only given once. Will this bias my meta-analysis in any way? Maybe artificially lower heterogeneity values?

Thanks,

G

Comment: Interesting problem. How many studies do you have in each categories (1, 2 & 3)?

Comment: I have about 200 studies in total. I'd need to write some code to get the precise numbers but around (1) n=30 (2) n=50 (3) = 120. I'm still in the process of adding more studies though!

Comment: Ouch, this makes the matter more complicated. If situation 3 were less abundant, I would have said drop them and keep the best. Could you make an odd ratio with all data types ?

Comment: Oh sorry i got that the wrong way around - (1) 30 (2) 120 (3) 50.

Comment: Is there a treatment in those studies (% of children who passed with/without the treatment or factor) ?

Comment: No i've only got proportions, i'm not looking at treatment or experimental effects,  there are no odds ratios. The outcome for each study is a proportion. However, because different studies use different methods, i'm interested in comparing the different studies together using meta-regression.

Comment: Then I think it goes beyond my knowledge. What effect size are you going to use to compare studies ?

Comment: I'm looking at the proportion of children that pass a cognitive test, the outcome that i'm comparing is the percentage succeeded on task. So i expect the outcome to differ due to factors such as age of the group, and other covariates, i'm interested in these covariates rather than any treatment effects. hope that's clear!

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any obvious way to bring together all three groups of studies. For group 3 it might be possible to treat them as group 1 but to use an imputed value for the standard deviations drawn from similar studies in group 1. The group 2 studies seem fundamentally different as the children only give one judgment whereas it is repeated in the other two groups.